# Running maven release on a successfully build - jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I need to be able to run a maven release procedure in the following way.
A manual jenkins job will be triggered, the maven release will build the artifacts according to the argument and the build procedure, in case it passes i want the job to trigger additional tests by calling other jenkins job, and only in case all passes to deploy it to artifactory.

Is this possible? or are there any better alternatives..?

Comment: I guess this is too broad. I would try to write a Declarative Pipeline for that, and come back when hitting a wall.

Comment: You can create 3 jobs and configure previous job's Post Action to trigger next job only when self build pass.  But recommend to writing Pipeline Script.